# Python to sort summed dictionary list values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I am having trouble sorting my summed values from highest to lowest.

The dict is setup like so:

```
dictionary = {name:[dollar amount 1, dollar amount 2, etc.]}
```

I need to sum the dollar amounts and print the results in descending order (by total of dollar amounts).

Currently I use this:

```
for pair in dictionary:
    print(pair, f'{sum(dictionary[pair]):.2f}')
```

I am not sure where or how to sort now and am only vaguely familiar with lambda usage.

Thank you!

Comment: Dictionaries are inherently not ordered, and therefore cannot be sorted. You have to put it in a (temporary) list or use OrderedDict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension, then `sorted` and iterate via a `for` loop:

```
from operator import itemgetter

# input dictionary; create new dictionary with values totalled
d = {'Joe': [5, 10, 15], 'Paul': [2, 5, 1], 'Andrew': [5, 20, 15]}
d_sums = {k: sum(v) for k, v in d.items()}

# sort by value descending and iterate, gives list of tuples
sums_sorted = sorted(d_sums.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

# iterate and print
for name, dollars in sums_sorted:
    print(f'{name} {dollars}')

# Andrew 40
# Joe 30
# Paul 8
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up following most of what you did but added the lambda from the suggestion below so as not to import anything.

Comment: @Iansberg, Sure; `itemgetter(1)` is *recommended* versus `lambda x: x[1]`, but it's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the sorted dictionary using lambda function!

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np
dictionary = {'xyx':np.random.randint(100,size=20),'xzy':np.random.randint(100,size=20),'xyz':np.random.randint(100,size=20)}

for i,j in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].sum(),reverse=True):
    print(i,j.sum())

#output:
xyx 1026
xzy 981
xyz 833
```